What is the 'deviceAdminSample' within the Device Administration Intent
I want to become a device admin hence need to send an intent to the user. From the code the only information I think I am missing is the deviceAdminSample. I dont know what this is referring to.
Having looked through the documentation (https://developer.android.com/work/device-admin#kotlin) it says deviceAdminSample is a DeviceAdminReceiver component.
However I have a DeviceAdminReceiver and cannot find this component anywhere.
fun buttonClick(view: View?): Boolean {
    binding.button?.text = binding.mainInputText?.text
    binding.button?.let { println(it.isClickable) }
    var REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN = 1;
    // Launch the activity to have the user enable our admin.
    val intent = Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN).apply {
        putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, deviceAdminSample)
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN)
    // return false - don't update checkbox until we're really active
    return false
}


Please edit your question to provide the relevant code parts as text instead of the screenshot so that the code can be easily copied.

Apologies. Done

It is a value of type ComponentName, the value should be ComponentName(this, AdminClassOrWhatever.class)
